# Bounds on functions using inequalities?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, functional-inequalities

I'm studying inequalities as part of a course on Numbers, Proofs and Mathematical Induction. There is one type of question that I don't understand, primarily because there's only one example in the notes and two questions. I need more examples/questions. Note that I don't need help with these specific questions, but I'd like to know how to do questions like this in general and to be pointed towards some more practice problems:

> Use the triangle inequality and other results to find an upper and lower bound for the following functions on the given interval:$$y=\frac{2x^2 + 1}{x+ 3}, |x|<1$$
>   $$y=\frac{x^3+3x+1}{10-x^2}, |x+1|<2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the triangle inequality and the "reverse triangle inequality",
$$|a\pm b|\le|a|+|b|\qquad\hbox{and}\qquad |a\pm b|\ge|a|-|b|\ .$$
For example, if $|x|<1$ then
$$|2x^2+1|\le 2|x|^2+|1|<3\ ;$$
also
$$|x+3|\ge|3|-|x|>2\ ,$$
so
$$\Bigl|\frac{1}{x+3}\Bigr|<\frac{1}{2}$$
and therefore
$$\Bigl|\frac{2x^2+1}{x+3}\Bigr|<\frac{3}{2}\ .$$
So $\frac{3}{2}$ is an upper bound for this expression when $|x|<1$.  Note that any larger number will also be an upper bound, and maybe if we did some more careful work we could find a smaller number which is still an upper bound.  This kind of question always has more than one answer.

Another approach would be to start by rewriting the expression algebraically:
$$\frac{2x^2+1}{x+3}=\frac{2(x+3)(x-3)+19}{x+3}=2(x-3)+\frac{19}{x+3}\ .$$
If $|x|<1$ then$$2(x-3)<-4\quad\hbox{and}\quad \frac{19}{x+3}<\frac{19}{2}$$
so
$$\frac{2x^2+1}{x+3}<\frac{11}{2}\ .$$
In this case, this result is not as precise as the one we obtained by the other method.

Comment: Thank you. How would you go about finding a lower bound?

Comment: Same ideas, but then you want the numerator greater than something and the denominator less than something.  Also you may have to be careful with the inequalities if there is any possibility that you are dealing with negative quantities.

Comment: BTW you also asked about more practice problems.  You could take more or less any function you like on any interval.  Here is one I just made up at random: $(x+5)/(x^2+3x+11)$ for $|x|\le2$.  Once you have found an answer you could check it by using graphics software to plot the function and confirm that the graph always lies between the upper and lower $y$-values you have found.

Comment: Thanks. So since in the second problem the domain is $-3<x<1$ I would have to watch the inequalities right? How would I deal with that? Just split it up into multiple cases? Also, when you use the reverse triangle inequality with a polynomial, how do you know where to put the negative signs? For example is of $|a+b+c|\ge|a|-|b|-|c|$?

Comment: In this case I think it's not so hard.  Remember negatives only matter in inequalities if you are multiplying or dividing, and in the second problem you never multiply or divide by $x$.  You do divide by $10-x^2$, but for $-3<x<1$ this is always positive, so no problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't know whether you would've seen the edit to my above comment: when you use the reverse triangle inequality with a polynomial, how do you know where to put the negative signs? For example is it $|a+b+c|\ge|a|-|b|-|c|$?

Comment: For reverse triangle inequality the numbers can go in any order, one of them minus all the others.  This is because, for example, $|a+b+c|$ is obviously the same as $|b+c+a|$.  For example, say $a=2$ and $b=-7$ and $c=-1$.  Then $|a+b+c|\ge|a|-|b|-|c|$ gives $|a+b+c|\ge-6$, which is true but pointless since you already know $|a+b+c|\ge0$.  On the other hand $|a+b+c|\ge|b|-|a|-|c|$ gives you a useful result.

Comment: Finally, since the original functions are not restricted by the absolute value signs that's introduced through using the triangle inequality, how do you get a useful result? For example, if the function's lower bound is negative, you're obviously not going to get that from the inequations because they are obviously greater than 0.

Comment: In that case the second method I suggested should still work, though once again you will have to be careful with the signs of inequalities.

Comment: Okay thanks for all your help. I have just one last question: the upper bound for the second function is given as $\frac{5}{9}$ in my book but no matter what I do I get 5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $5$ would be a valid answer - anything bigger than an upper bound is still an upper bound.  But the book probably said $x<1$, so $x^3+3x+1<5$ and $10-x^2>9$, so $(x^3+3x+1)/(10-x^2)<\frac{5}{9}$.